# Laravel firstOrNew with multiple conditions?

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have a model called `Stock` and I want to insert or update a row (if its already exists).
The table has 6 columns:

```
drink_id
flow_id
bought
left
created_at
updated_at
```

With jQuery I collect the data, pass it through with ajax. The data arrives but the following code does not work properly:

```
$row = Stock::firstOrNew(array( 'drink_id'  => $drink_id,
                'flow_id'   => $max_flow));


$row -> bought = $bought;
$row -> left = $left;
$row -> save();
```

I got the following error:

```
{"error":
   {
    "type":"Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException",
    "message":"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id'
        in 'where clause' (SQL: update `stock` set `bought` = 22,
        `updated_at` = 2014- 05-18 09:10:14 where `id` is null)",
        "file":"C:\\wamp\\www\\csabi\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connection.php",
        "line":539
   }
}
```

Comment: This seems strange: Laravel tries to do an update, so that would mean that they is already an item with that drink_id and flow_id in the datase, but at the same time, when it saves it, it can't find the id. Could you please dump the $row to see what attributes are defined

Comment: Yep. And if I use just $item -> save(); it should work as save or update, but it creates a new record.

Comment: Are you sure the variables are correct? It says "where `id` is null" in your sql query.

Comment: First thing was review all the variables, column names.
Is it problem if my table does not contain column named 'id'?
I shouldn't but what if.. :\

Comment: Please show the code of your Stock model.

Comment: Model is this simple:
class Stock extends Eloquent {

 protected $table = 'stock';

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem was that Laravel doesn't support composit primary keys so I had to add a new 'id' row to the table.